# android: sort contacts/items by checked checkbox

Tags: sorting, checkbox, android-contacts

I created a ListActivity. 
in every item in list, i binded contact name and check-box using custom adapter.
Now i want to sort my contacts by checked check-boxes,first checked and then others.

Is there a quick way for doing this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know whether you can sort by checkboxes or not. But there is another way of achieving your purpose. Just create a database consisting of all contact names and one more field initialized to zero for every contact name(you can call it flag). Bind the contact names with list view and implement it in such a way whenever an item on a contactlist is clicked flag for that contact name is set to 1. Then you can sort the list easily based on the number of checked flags.